Find minimal sufficient statistic of this random sample with cursed support
Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a i.i.d random sample with probability mass function $p(x_i,\theta)$ where $x_i \in \{\theta,\theta+1,\theta+2,...\}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. I claim that minimal sufficient statistic is $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$. Am I right?
Special case
If it is hard to find a minimal sufficient statistic for this problem, you can consider a special case where $p(x_i,\theta)=p(x_i)$ which means p does not depend on $\theta$.
General case
I also believe that my claim is true when $\theta \in A$ where $card(A) \ge 2$.
My Approach
If you try to use factorization theorem:
$$P(\textbf{X}=\textbf{x}) = {\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(x_i,\theta) I_{ \{ \theta,\theta+1,...\} }(x_i) }$$where $I_{ \{ \theta,\theta+1,...\} }(x_i)$ is the indicator function. This is where we can't do anything because we can't factor the product of indicator functions, so I guess the minimal sufficient statistic is $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)}) $.
My Interpretation
I think ${\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} I_{ \{ \theta,\theta+1,...\} }(x_i) }$ means "in order to find out $x_i$ is a valid observation, we need to know $\theta$ "
My Question
Is $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$ the minimal sufficient statistic?
I also asked this question in Cross Validated.
